# Create object that is invisible to the RangeFinder sensor

Tags: webots, rangefinder

The title says it all. I would like to have object that the rangeFinder can't see. This would help me to model real life shiny objects for a ToF sensor in webots. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the visibility of nodes w.r.t. rendering devices ([Camera](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/camera), [Lidar](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/lidar), [RangeFinder](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/rangefinder) or [Viewpoint](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/viewpoint)) using the [Supervisor](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor) function [`wb_supervisor_node_set_visibility`](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_node_set_visibility).

If your robot equipped with the [RangeFinder](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/rangefinder) has `supervisor` functionalities (i.e. the `Robot.supervisor` field is set to TRUE) you can simply set the objects visibility directly in the robot controller.
Otherwise, you might need to add an empty [Robot](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/robot) node in your world, with `supervisor` field set to TRUE,  that sets the nodes visibility at the very beginning of the simulation.

Here is a sample python controller to set the visibility that retrieves both the object and [RangeFinder](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/rangefinder) nodes using the DEF name:

```py
from controller import Supervisor

supervisor = Supervisor()
range_finder = supervisor.getFromDef("RANGE_FINDER")
hidden_object= supervisor.getFromDef("HIDDEN_OBJECT")
hidden_object.setVisibility(range_finder, False)
```

*Disclaimer: I'm part of the Webots development team.*